# Springboot Embedded postgresql for unit test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am using the https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test to test my repositories. However whenever I am testing my repository the entity is not created. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I mock my repository using @MockBean.

Comment: You are using a mock hence no database is being used.

Comment: Use H2 database instead of mocking

Comment: Based upon all your comments I can see that the embedded postgres  https://github.com/zonkyio/embedded-database-spring-test does not actually help in unit testing. I really do not want to use H2